# VB.Net Uncheck selected index in checkedlistbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a checked list box, if I check an item on it it will show the checked item on a listbox but only if that item exists on a database table. Everything works fine except if the data isn't on the table the checkbox remains checked. here's my code

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
  'Database Query here

  If data is on table then
      Listbox1.items.add(CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
  Else
      CheckedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex, CheckState.Unchecked)
      'Unchecking the checked checkbox because data isn't on the table, i'm having problems here, the checkbox remains checked.
  end if

Else

  Listbox1.items.remove(CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

End if

end sub
```

Comment: Looking at your code, that wouldn't even compile unless you put that "If data is on table then" just for explaining purposes? I'm still confused on what you want to happen and where your stuck at?

Answer (score 1):

The CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck method handling the CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck event.

Rather than trying to SetItemCheckState of the item that was clicked, try using the reference passed into the method:

```
e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
```

Also, rather than referring to the SelectedItem, you'd probably be best to ensure you're getting the value from the item that was checked:

```
CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString()
```